# UAC and running an exe from Notepad++ with UseShellExecute

Tags: c#, notepad++, uac, runas

I know this question was asked before, in several ways, still, I haven't found an answer for my specific scenario, so I'll be glad for any help.

I'm writing a Notepad++ plugin, in which the user click on a button and an exe file starts running in the background, using:

```
UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

etc..., I'm redirecting the output to NPP window.

Now, as I've encountered problems running this exe I've eventually found what's wrong. The famous UAC.

Since I'm running it at work stations (which their users are NOT the admin), is there any way to run this exe file in the background (with parameters), without seeing the shell window, because, if the shell window is shown, I cannot redirect its output to NPP (right?) with some 'hack' overcoming the admin issue?

As I've understood, using the `verb="runas"` cannot work with `UseShellExecute = false`, so basically what it mean is, if I want to successfully run this exe file from within Notepad++, I cannot redirect its output to the Notepad++.

Am I doomed? Is my project a flop?

Please help...

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot launch an elevated process from a non-elevated process under UAC without the administrator credentials being supplied. If you could, it would be a major security hole that any and all malware could exploit. The fact that your question is about an NPP plugin doesn't change the fact that it's the same question being asked again. (*I saw the question about adding two int variables named a and b, but my variables are x and y*.) This has been asked and answered literally dozens of times here before. Attempts to circumvent UAC always fail, and always indicate a fatal flaw in your design.

Comment: ok. thx. I'll try also outputting the data to external file, than sending it back to NPP.

Comment: What if you put the other exe process inside a  .bat, and there redirecting the output to, say, a file. Then run it as a cmd line and then reading the file?